# FuelPHP Pagination Issue

Tags: php, pagination, fuelphp

I recently upgraded my FuelPHP to v1.5. Now I'm trying to set up the pagination class.

This is my code:

```
$data['news'] = Model_News::find()->where('font', '>', -1);
        $count = count($data['news']);

        $config = array(
                'pagination_url' => 'http://localhost/public/mobile/barbecue/',
                'total_items'    => $count,
                'per_page'       => 12,
                'uri_segment'    => 3,
        );

        $pagination = Pagination::forge('mypagination', $config);

        $data['news'] = Model_News::find()->where('font', '>', -1)->order_by(array('date' => 'desc'))->limit($pagination->per_page)->offset($pagination->offset)->get();
        $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();
        $this->template->title = "Teams";
        $this->template->content = View::forge('news/index', $data);
```

I made a copy of the `core/config/pagination.php` to `app/config/pagination.php`. 
And on my view `news/index.php` the pagination is seted: `<?php echo $pagination ?>`

Result:the information obtained by the query are displayed normally, but the string $ pagination returns nothing. Fuel displays no error.

What I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In new version of Fuelphp, do this changes in view:

```
echo html_entity_decode($pagination);
```

And update the pagination config file.
Below are some change given.

```
'previous-marker'         => "<",
//and
'next-marker'             => ">"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, print the pagination with:

```
<?php echo \Pagination::create_links(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $pagination ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For FuelPHP v1.5+, that would be

```
<?php echo $pagination->render(); ?>
```